# Trouble getting two monitors to play simultaneously without being choppy?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, graphics-card

I'm having a weird problem with Windows 7, a decent graphics card (GeForce GTX 650 Ti 1GB 128-bit GDDR5 PCI Express 3.0 x16), and simultaneously watching video and playing a video game.

I'm trying to watch a simple movie with a pretty low bitrate, and playing Fallout 3. My graphics card can easily play Fallout on maximum settings, but no matter what setting I put it on, the game plays smoothly, but the movie on the other monitor has a slight chop to it, like a stutter, about once per second.

It seems that there isn't a hardware bottleneck, as the graphics card, the i5 processor and 16GB RAM must be more than enough to handle the dual operations. I can't think of what I need to do to eliminate the stutter in the movie.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried moving the video to another physical disk if you have one?

Comment: Yes, I've run both from separate disks at the same time, and there is no change. Also, even if the game is just on its splash screen, the movie stutters. Once I minimize the game and hide its window, the stuttering stops. I also tried updating my graphics drivers to the latest version!  Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you checked the CPU usage while both are running? Are all cores being utilised or is one core getting maxed out while the rest are idle?

Comment: *"It seems that there isn't a hardware bottleneck"* - On what evidence do you base this conclusion?  You have to consider I/O bandwidth separately from processing bandwidth.  You are trying to run two video streams.  Video frames are time sensitive; they have to be generated on time, or you see stutter.  A movie "with a pretty low bitrate" still has to be decoded to its full resolution, and then scaled down to its window size.  Seems like the GPU is dedicating its primary resources to the game.  Can you install or configure the movie to play using a software decoder (i.e. not use the GPU)?

Comment: Regarding hardware bottleneck - according to resource monitor as well as using GeForce's tool to monitor graphics cards usage, nothing is ever even getting near 50% utilization. Thanks for the ideas @sawdust...I have tried using VLC for playing the movie both with and without graphics card acceleration, to no avail.